# sum of all digits in the number by python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, integer

I am trying to write a python program to calculate sum of digits of a number.
and please explain it line by line as I am new please.

I am screeching it online and found something like this :-

```
sum = 0
while (n != 0):       
    sum = sum + (n % 10)
    n = n//10
```

I don't understand the use of these 2 line please explain it

```
sum = sum + (n % 10)
n = n//10
```

and suggest me if you guys know any another way to solve it quick and easily?
thank you

Comment: Don't use Python *built-in*  *sum* as the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Extract the last digit of the number
(n % 10)
```

Using the modulus operator (`%`) to get the remainder when n is divided by 10. (e.g., if `n` is 123, then `n % 10` would be 3)

```
# Add it to the sum
sum = sum + (n % 10)
```

This is to just add it to the `sum` variable.

```
# Remove the last digit from the number
n //= 10
```

Using the floor division operator (`//`) to divide `n` by 10 and assign the result back to `n`. For example, if `n` is 123, then `n // 10` would be 12.

Answer (score 0):

so basically while loop runs till n becomes 0 let's take an example given
`n=2438` initially sum is `0`

checking is `n==0` no...   Enter the while loop

```
`sum = sum + (n % 10)` -> sum=0+8  as 2438%10=8 which is remainder..!
`n = n//10` -> n=243 after division as you can see the last digit is removed ..!
```

check is `n==0` no.. enter the loop

```
`sum = sum + (n % 10)` -> sum=8+3  as 243%10=3 which is remainder..!
`n = n//10` -> n=24 after division as you can see the last digit is removed ..!
```

as you can see above two steps .

```
sum=11+4
n=2

sum=15+2
n=0
```

check is n==0 yes the while loop breaks..!

print the sum as you have obtained the result

As you are beginner you should come up with the simple answer like..

```
n=2438
n=str(n)      #   2438 converted into "2438"
total_sum_of_digit=0
for i in n:   # loop runs as it converted into string..
    total_sum_of_digit+=int(i)   #converted string digit to int digit and add into total_sum_of_digit
print(total_sum_of_digit)
```

List comprehension is better option.. but you should go with the beginner level to the such above topics..